# How to compose to functions several times?

Tags: python, function

I'm supposed to write a code which gets a mathematical function and a number and gives me as an output a function that is composed n times.

For example if `n=3` I would get `f(f(f(x)))`.

When I run my code I get an error, what should I fix in it?

Running examples :

```
>>> repeated(lambda x:x*x, 2)(5)
624
>>> repeated(lambda x:x*x, 4)(3)
43046721
```

This is my code :

```
def repeated(f, n):
    g=f
    for i in range(n):
        g=lambda x: (g(g(x)))
    return (g)
```

Comment: Do tell us *what the error is* you get!

Comment: I don't know which error it is exactly, When I run it Python goes crazy writing down stuff in red non stop so I had to close and reopen it.

Comment: Well, you are rebinding `g` to something that calls itself twice when invoked; that'll probably lead to an infinite recursion.

Comment: It would be wonderful if the `*` operator could be applied to callables for composition, with `(f*g)(x)` being identical to `f(g(x))`. Then `**` could be naturally defined to provide repeated composition: `(f**3)(x) = (f*f*f)(x) = f(f(f(x)))`.

Comment: @chepner I composed an answer with a callable that has that feature.

Answer (score 4):

Return a new function that does the repeated applying *only when called*:

```
def repeated(f, n):
    def repeat(arg):
        return reduce(lambda r, g: g(r), [f] * n, arg)
    return repeat
```

The `reduce()` method uses the list of `f` function references to create the right number of nested calls, starting with `arg` as the first argument.

Demo:

```
>>> def repeated(f, n):
...     def repeat(arg):
...         return reduce(lambda r, g: g(r), [f] * n, arg)
...     return repeat
... 
>>> repeated(lambda x:x*x, 2)(5)
625
>>> repeated(lambda x:x*x, 4)(3)
43046721
```

A version that doesn't use `reduce()` would be:

```
def repeated(f, n):
    def repeat(arg):
        res = arg
        for _ in range(n):
            res = f(res)
        return res
    return repeat
```

Comment: For Python 3 you will need to import `reduce` from `functools`, IIRC

Comment: @kojiro: indeed; `try: reduce`, `except NameError: from functools import reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context of your task (e.g. programming class), you might be interested in following straightforward solution:

```
def repeated(f,  n):
  if n < 1:
    raise ValueError()
  elif n == 1:
    return f
  else:
    return lambda x: repeated(f, n-1)(f(x))
```

This is a naive recursive solution, which maps more directly to the requirements. If you already know about higher functions, such as `reduce` I suggest to go with Martijn Pieters solutions. Nevertheless this does work:

```
>>> repeated(lambda x:x*x, 2)(5)
625
>>> repeated(lambda x:x*x, 4)(3)
43046721
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was an interesting enough problem that I wanted to think about it for a couple days before answering. I've created a set of generalizable, pythonic (I think), ways for composing a function on itself in the way described in the question. The most generic solution is just `nest`, which returns a generator that yields successively nested values of the function on the initial argument. Everything else builds off that, but the decorators could be implemented using one of the above solutions, as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Attempt to create a callable that can compose itself using operators
Also attempt to create a function-composition decorator.

    f(x) composed once is f(x)
    f(x) composed twice is f(f(x))
    f(x) composed thrice is f(f(f(x)))

This only makes sense at all if the function takes at least one argument:

    f() * 2 -> f(?)

But regardless of its arity, a function can only return exactly one value (even if that value is iterable). So I don't think it makes sense for the function to have >1 arity, either. I could unpack the result:

    f(x, y) * 2 -> f(*f(x, y))

But that introduces ambiguity -- not every iterable value should be unpacked. Must I inspect the function to tell its arity and decide whether or not to unpack on the fly? Too much work!

So for now, I just ignore cases other than 1-arity.
"""
def nest(func, arg):
    """Generator that calls a function on the results of the previous call.
    The initial call just returns the original argument."""
    while True:
        yield arg
        arg = func(arg)

def compose(n):
    """Return a decorator that composes the given function on itself n times."""
    if n < 1: raise ValueError
    def decorator(func):
        def nested(arg):
            gen = nest(func, arg)
            for i in range(n):
                next(gen)
            return next(gen)
        return nested
    return decorator

class composable(object):
    """A callable that can be added and multiplied."""
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __add__(self, func2):
        """self(func2(x))"""
        def added(a):
            return self(func2(a))
        return composable(added)
    def __mul__(self, n):
        """self * 3 => self(self(self(a)))"""
        def nested(a):
            gen = nest(self, a)
            for i in range(n):
                next(gen)
            return next(gen)
        return composable(nested)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

@compose(2)
def sq(x):
    return x*x

@compose(4)
def qu(x):
    return x*x

@composable
def add1(x):
    return x + 1

compset = composable(set)

assert (compset + str.split)('abc def') == set(['abc', 'def']), (compset + str.split)('abc def')
assert add1(1) == 2, add1(1)
assert (add1 + (lambda x: x * x))(4) == 17, (add1 + (lambda x: x * x))(4)
assert (add1 * 3)(5) == 8, (add1 * 3)(5)

assert 625 == sq(5), sq(5)
assert 43046721 == qu(3), qu(3)
```

Comment: I agree that a function with no arguments should not compose with itself. The key to self-composition is that the return value should match the arguments, so `f(x,y) * 2 -> f(*f(x,y))` (where `f` returns a 2-tuple whose commensurate with the arguments expected by `f`). However, the interesting applications of composition usually involve different functions. For example, a function to build a set from a space-separated string: `lambda x: set(x.split())` vs. `set * x.split`.

Comment: @chepner I updated the answer to address those points. The arity thing I address in the docstring, because I don't think it's worth introducing that much magic into the code. I also demonstrate a composable set toward the bottom.

Comment: Looks good; I'm just bemoaning the fact that Python doesn't provide operators for functions. I realized that even `*` isn't a great choice, because defining `(f*g)(x)` as `f(x)*g(x)` makes sense, and (as long as I'm dreaming), adding U+2218 as a function-specific operator would *awesome* :), so that `(f∘g)(x)` would be equivalent to `f(g(x))`. I'd even be fine with Python ignoring the arity issue until you actually tried to call such a composed function, since functions don't have a fixed return type anyway.

Comment: @chepner I did try to update the function metaclass, but Python doesn't allow it. :( No hax 4 u.